# Setting up a system to move multiple channels across multiple catagory

Tags: python, discord

Im trying to get a system to check all catagories in my server and when a solution is found move the channel into 1 of the 10 categories (filling up from top to bottom) maxing at 45 channels

This is the current code i use (creates a new catagory once full rather than sorting into the current catagories

```
                if solution:
                  await channel.clone()
         # If solution found, move to new category and sync.
                  category_name = 'Original'
                  guild = message.guild
                  old_category = channel.category
                  new_category = [c for c in guild.categories if c.name == category_name][0]
                  num_channels = len(new_category.channels)
                  print(f"There are {num_channels} channels in the {category_name} category.")
                  if len(new_category.channels) >= 45:
                    await new_category.edit(name="Stock")
                    new_category = await new_category.clone(name='Original')
                     # create a new category with the old name
                  new_category_name = new_category.name
                  await channel.edit(name=solution[0].lower().replace(' ', '-'), category=new_category)
                  await asyncio.sleep(2)
                  await channel.edit(sync_permissions=True)
```

How would i check for the number of channels under the category and then file it under the next if the first is full? And repeat for categories 3-10?

Comment: the question needs sufficient code for a minimal reproducible example:
https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example